# Загрузка формата .obj в DirectX9

Tags: c++, c, directx, obj

Помогите загрузить Wireframe Object(*.obj) в DirectX. Я написал алгоритм, но DirectX не верно освещает сцену. Нормали взяты из файла, но они либо не верные, либо я что-то не так делаю. Высчитывал куб в ручную - освещение адекватное. А с загрузкой проблемы. Код большой, но по надобности добавлю. Такое ощущение, что в самом формате баг(ясное дело, что это не так)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в расстановке индексов в файле. Уверен, кому-нибудь пригодится:

Индексы 22/3/4

22 - индекс вершины
3 - индекс текстуры(а я думал, нормали, да и в туториалах было указано, что нормали)
4 - индекс нормали

Все заработало.